# input file "No File Choosen" text hide using button in jquery MultiFile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have following input file

```
<input type="file" id="sampleInput" name="files" onchange="return Plugins.sampleAction(this);"/>
```

In this file input I'm trying to remove "No File Choosen" text, for that I did following modification

```
<input type="file" id="sampleInput" name="files" onchange="return Plugins.sampleAction(this);" style='display:none'/>
 <button id="image_alt" type="button">Select image</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#image_alt').addEventListener('click', function () {
        $('#sampleInput').click();
    });
</script>
```

but when I click button this one not opening the file up-loader window

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 $('#image_alt').on('click', function () {
        $('#sampleInput').click();
    });
```

addEventListener is the javascript way to listen for events, but you call it on a JQuery object. Give a look at JQuery.on() to manage events using JQuery.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: So this means your Jquery file path is wrong.Please user any cdna for testing on the same page where you want to run your code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button id="image_alt" type="button">Select image</button>
  <p class="file_selected">File name</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#image_alt').on('click', function () {
        $('#sampleInput').click();
    });
    function changeVal(obj,cnt){
       $(cnt).text($(obj).val());
    }
</script>
```