# dynamically create input file element in jQuery MultiFile plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onchange

I'm using jQuery MultiFile plugin, this is a ordinary view of that plugin

[image]

this is the **HTML** syntax for this

```
<input type="file" id="someName" name="file" class="multi" onchange="return Plugins.handleFileSelect(this);"/>
```

I'm trying to generate this file input dynamically

So I tried to append this once "click here" button click happens

```
 <button type="button" id="ifile">click here</button>             
 <div id="target_div"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#ifile').click(function () {
        // when the add file button is clicked append
        // a new <input type="file" name="someName" />
        // to a target_div div
        $('#target_div').append(
            $('<input/>').attr('type', "file").attr('name', "file").attr('id', "someName").attr('class', "multi").attr('onchange', "return Plugins.handleFileSelect(this);")
        );
    });
</script>
```

but once I do this its generating ordinary file input but its not listing files properly

once I open inspect elements I can see a view like following

[image]

how can I generate this properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use MultiFile plugin instead

```
$('#ifile').click(function () {
    // when the add file button is clicked append
    // a new <input type="file" name="someName" />
    // to a target_div div
    var input = $('<input/>')
                .attr('type', "file")
                .attr('name', "file")
                .attr('id', "someName");
    //append the created file input
    $('#target_div').append(input);
    //initializing Multifile on the input element
    input.MultiFile();
});
```

Comment: your answer very accurate, I wish if you can answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466136/input-file-no-file-choosen-text-hide-using-button) too which is hide "No file choosen text in above multifile input" 

and I have [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468973/shorten-the-lengthy-label-name-using-substring-or-substr-in-jquery-multifile) which is shorten the lengthy label name in jQuery MultiFile

Answer (score 0):

you can use append like this

```
$('#target_div').append('<input type="file" id="someName" name="file" class="multi" onchange="return Plugins.handleFileSelect(this);"/>')
```

btw you can check the jquery documentation for append

http://api.jquery.com/append/